# Dynamically create link based on parent page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a lot of pages in Wordpress which have almost the same URL despite the Parent page being different.

An example URL would be:

(Parent URL)/need-to-know

How would I go about selecting the parent URL and adding it to a simple link in HTML?

I tried creating a shortcode using the following:

```
function need_to_know_link() {
 if ($post->post_parent) {
    $parent_link = get_permalink($post->post_parent); 
    echo '<a href="'. $parent_link .'/need-to-know">Need to Know</a>';
}
}
add_shortcode( 'need_to_know', 'need_to_know_link' );
```

UPDATE:

I removed the if statement and the code works correctly. Is there any reason why the if statement would cause it to not work?

Comment: `echo '<a href="'. $parent_link .'/need-to-know">/need-to-know</a>';` I think it is correct, or I am not getting you

Comment: So, what happens when you run your short code? You need to explain the issue you're having with the posted code. We're not here to guess...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Updated.

Comment: @RahulMeshram Still not working but yes I do see where I made an error in how I coded it. Updated the main question, thank you!

Comment: This is most likely [a scoping issue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). In your function, you can't use the variable `$post` since it will be undefined/non-existing in that scope. If you turn on error reporting and look at your error log, you will probably find some "undefined variable" warnings.